# MySQL 8.0 lower_case_table_names 1

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-8.0

I am setting up MySQL 8.0 on a new Ubuntu 18.04 VM but I am not able to setup the variable lower_case_table_names to 1 . 
I have tried changing  /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf [mysqld] as in previous versions but had no success and cannot restart mysql service. 
This must be specific to 8.0 as I am able to set this in previous versions.

Comment: Please add some details and logs of error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows and the only way I found to fix it was to uninstall/reinstall MySql server. During installation, I was able to specify upper case for table names.